# How can Amazon EC2 Server change instance type without moving data file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently, I am using Amazon EC2 C1-medium server to run my service. I heard that Amazon EC2 server made a new type server called, Amazon EC2 C3. Amazon EC2 C3 offers SSD hard disk.

I was wondering I can change Instance Type without moving my old data files, and I believe that they can do it because they are using normal hard disk. However, I found out that I can change the instance type even though I want to change my old server to SSD hard disk.

I didn't change the type yet because I worry about losing server data. I read documents but couldn't find the answer. How does it work and is it safe to do it?

Comment: amazon's pretty good at what they do ... I would take a snapshot of the image (as a fail safe) then move to the c3 instance (pretty sure you need to shut down in order to move so you may need to do something else if server is actively serving users)

Comment: It makes sense. So, they actually move same files and Linux system to new instance. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. the OS , and all files (and anything you have installed, php, ruby etc) is refereed to as the an image. so if this is live serving users you could create image (right click on instance in management console) and launch this on larger instance then shutdown old instance. If the server can be down for a few minutes shutdown and then just change instance type

Comment: Now, I can understand how it works. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to change the type of a running instance is:

1. Stop (do not terminate) the instance (`stop-instances`).
2. Modify the type of the instance (`modify-instance-attribute`).
3. Start the instance (`start-instances`).

There are a number of cautions that you should be aware of including:

- This only works for EBS based instances.
- The ephemeral storage (often mounted on `/mnt`) will be lost.
- You may have to re-associate an Elastic IP address if the instance is not in a VPC.

This can be done through the console, command line, or API calls.  Here's an old article I wrote about changing instance types using the command line tools: http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-change-type

I definitely recommend converting from `c1.medium` to `c3.large` as you are thinking. Here's an article I wrote about that: http://alestic.com/2013/12/ec2-instance-type-c3

Since you're interested in SSD, note that the SSD on the `c3.large` is *ephemeral storage*. Data stored there will be lost irretrievably when an instance is terminated, stopped, or fails. You'll want to only store files you can afford to lose there (e.g., ones that are replicated elsewhere, backed up regularly, or possible to regenerate).

Comment: I decided to move from c1.medium to c3.large instance. But found out that c3.large option is not available while using web console ( see screenshot [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/758d5702-ea61-4f22-863e-68a6a83f1dc9/4277119600b7556911a3885d32243929) ) . Why this happens? Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like 32-bit OSes are NOT allowed for c3.large instances.

Comment: @erop Good to know. I think only supporting 64 bit will be a continuing trend and recommend using 64 bit everywhere: http://alestic.com/2012/03/ec2-64-bit

Comment: Minor update - Amazon now offers SSDs for non-ephemeral storage, even without using Provisioned IOPS.  Sadly, the process for updating to SSD is a more complicated, especially for a database in active use which is forbidden from having downtime longer than a reboot or so.

Comment: @EricHammond wouldn't stopping and restarting the instance result in loss of data stored on the RAM? Creating an AMI and then spinning of an instance with the required instance type would not result in any data loss? Right?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a image of this instance, and then launch a new instance with this image, you are data in EBS will saved, but the data in instance storage will lose, because this storage is  ephemeral storage, when the server is shut down your are date in ephemeral storage will lost. Generally we don't save data in my EC2 hard disk, alteratively we save useful data in s3, which is a unlimit hard disk. AWS's official advice is only save log file or temp file in instance storage.